# Newtonsoft JsonConvert with non-standard keys?

Tags: .net, json, wpf

I am using NewtonSoft's JsonConvert for .NET. I am retrieving my json from here:

http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks

The resulting JSON is as follows:

```
"recenttracks": {
    "track": [{
        "artist": {
            "#text": "Van Halen",
            "mbid": "b665b768-0d83-4363-950c-31ed39317c15"
        },
        "name": "Dreams",
        "streamable": "0",
        "mbid": "0fc4adac-20b9-4309-8060-8ecf1360d458",
        "album": {
            "#text": "Best of Van Halen, Volume 1",
            "mbid": ""
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Van+Halen\/_\/Dreams",
        "image": [{
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/98202743.jpg",
            "size": "small"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/98202743.jpg",
            "size": "medium"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/98202743.jpg",
            "size": "large"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/98202743.jpg",
            "size": "extralarge"
        }],
        "@attr": {
            "nowplaying": "true"
        }
    }],
}
```

Ideally, I would access details of the json as follows:

```
MessageBox.Show(json.recenttracks.track[0].artist.ToString());
```

That would echo out the contents of the artist field. However, I only want to echo out the contents of the 'artist[#text]' field. I dont know how to retrieve this data, as I cant use # as an identifier. How do I get this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JsonProperty` attribute to specify which key should be mapped to what property.

In your case this would be

```
[JsonProperty("#text")]
public string Text {get; set;}
```